# heroku - Google Cloud Storage H13 "Connection closed without response"

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, google-cloud-storage, multer

I am trying to deploy my application on Heroku using Google Cloud Storage to store my images. All my images are streamed into GCS. However, whenever I try to upload, Heroku returns me a h13 error.

Here is the portion of Code that is causing problems:

```
//upload
router.post('/upload', multer.single('upload_image'), (req, res) => {

if (!req.file) {
    res.send('No File Was Uploaded')
}
const type = mime.lookup(req.file.originalname);

const blob = artImagesBucket.file(`${Date.now()}_${req.file.originalname}.${mime.extensions[type][0]}`);

const stream = blob.createWriteStream({
    resumable: true,
    contentType: type,
    predefinedAcl: 'publicRead',
});

stream.on('error', err => {
    next(err);
});

stream.on('finish', () => {
    let time = Date.now();
        let date_ob = new Date(time);
        let date = date_ob.getDate();
        let month = date_ob.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
        const fullDate = year + "-" +month+ "-"+date

        var uploadQuery = "INSERT INTO uploads (user_upload, image, title, description, upload_date, like_count, comment_count) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,0,0)"
        db.query(uploadQuery, [req.session.passport.user.username, blob.name, req.body.uploadTitle, req.body.uploadDescription, fullDate], (err, results) => {
            res.redirect('/profile')
        })
});

stream.end(req.file.buffer);
})
```

Here is the Heroku Log:
2020-05-10T01:57:49.109286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/upload" host=rate-my-art.herokuapp.com request_id=143cd007-8ccb-460f-8588-3ac51ac980bb fwd="191.253.138.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=598ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: Could you please share the error logs from Google Stackdriver Logging for Google Cloud Storage after uploading to Heroku?

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, it was an issue in regards to me calling the next() function without defining it on the parameters